# android how to put progressdialog in TabActivity

Tags: android, progressdialog

I hav an application where I have an TabActivity and which have 2tabs(each tab as an activity)
First tab(an activity) loads data from internet.
So I want there a progressdialog until the 1st tab(an activity) loads data from internet.

```
ProgressDialog.show(TabHostActivity.this, "Working..", "Downloading Data...",true);
pd.dismiss();
```

only this much code i have which not give satisfaction
please anybody tell me what i write to show a progressdialog until it download the data.
(means i hav to use thread).
Please give me answer along with code
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In tabGroupActivity ,use progressDialog in the folllowing way( If your activity is the sub Activity of any tabhost):

```
ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "Working..", "Downloading Data...",true);
```

try this, and one more thing implement ProgressDialog using threads:
see this for help : [How to get a progress bar on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197529/how-to-get-a-progress-bar-on-button-click/)

Hope this will  give you some idea on the topic.

Comment: Why to take care of Thread if there is already a Painless threading i.e. AsyncTask provided by Android

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) inside the First Tab activity, Asynctask is known as [PainLess Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Just go through the above 2 links and then do as follows:

1. call dialog.show() method inside the doInBackground() method.
2. call dialog.dismiss() method inside the onPostExecute() method.